The horror movie about some sort of terrible creatures from the deep
Cannot find a movie, that I've watched on VHS in my childhood.
It's a horror movie from the 90s.
Action took place in a little town on the seaside. One day terrible creatures that lived in the sea (and in the town sewers) started to kill and abduct people. And they abducted mostly women, as I remember. People started investigation and finally found a some kind of nest, where all kidnapped women was hold. And one important note: in the final scene a creature was born from the belly of one of saved women. Almost like in "Aliens".
Also it seems that the title was "Humanoids from the deep", "Aliens from the deep", "Terror from the deep" or something like that.

Sounds like Humanoids from the Deep (1980)

Scientific experiments backfire and produce horrific mutations: 
  halfman, halffish which terrorize a small fishing village by killing 
  the men and raping the women.


Yep, almost, but I've actually found what I wanted. And the title is the same. Thx though.

It's so strange that I could not find a movie even knowing the exact title. I've been looking for it wrong translation.
It is "Humanoids from the Deep (1996)".

Humanoids from the Deep is an independent American television movie of
  the science fiction and horror genres. It was written and directed by
  Jeff Yonis based on a short story by Martin B. Cohen. The movie is a
  remake of the 1980 feature film, Humanoids from the Deep by director
  Barbara Peeters.


You might want to add in which way this fits to the details from the question in order to flesh out this answer a little more.

Even if answer my own question?:)

Yes, even then. The answer is not only for you but for everyone reading this question. We are building an archive of engaging questions together with their explanative answers here. Knowing that you think this is the correct answer without any way for the community to realize that won't help with that.

Don't forget to accept the answer if it is the correct solution to your problem.
